# How to fix Show category in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I'm building a ticket system i made tables with heads as:

```
<table class="table">
     <thead>
            <tr>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Last Updated</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
```

I'm having trouble calling category name in views:

```
@foreach ($tickets as $ticket)
@foreach ($categories as $category)
           @if ($category->id === $ticket->category_id)
                  {{ $category->name }}
           @endif
@endforeach
```

My @if statements seems to be wrong i thinks as i can pull all the category names but with @if code seems to be breaking and its showing me nothing.

My routes:

```
Route::get('my_tickets', 'TicketsController@userTickets');
```

My Controller Function:

```
public function userTickets()
    {
        $tickets = Ticket::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->paginate(10);
        $categories = Category::all();

        return view('tickets.user_tickets', compact('tickets', 'categories'));
    }
```

Update:
My Category Model:

```
protected $fillable = ['name'];
public function tickets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Ticket::class);
    }
```

&Ticket Model:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'category_id', 'ticket_id', 'title', 'priority', 'message', 'status'
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
```

I'm trying to follow this tutorial but i think I'm doing something wrong idk what.
https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-support-ticket-application-with-laravel-part-1
https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-support-ticket-application-with-laravel-part-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are trying to do something like this:

```
@foreach ($tickets as $ticket)
{{ $ticket->category->name }}
@endforeach
```

If you made a relation between your classes with belongsTo and hasMany then you can access using $ticket->category->name. If it does not work perhaps you have to get tickets with:

```
$tickets = Ticket::with('category')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->paginate(10);
```

Comment: it worked i forgot about i can use "$ticket->category->name"! thanks

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really followed it through. See how it's done in the article

```
@foreach ($tickets as $ticket)
  @foreach ($categories as $category)
    @if ($category->id === $ticket->category_id)
        {{ $category->name }}
    @endif
  @endforeach
```

`$ticket->$category` is not a valid syntax.

Comment: yes I've tested that code first which didn't worked by using this code its showing category empty

Comment: ```$category->id === $ticket->id``` will not work properly. Sure, some id will accidentally match, but you want to check ```$category->id === $ticket->category_id```

Comment: can you update the question with ticket and category models?

Comment: @Sumitkumar can you manually check your `ticket category_id` is equal to the `category id`?

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya my database's ticket has relationship which connects to category by category_id column

Comment: @Sumitkumar I have understood the relationship as your tutorials. `@if ($category->id === $ticket->category_id)` is it not work? Update your blade file.
if category is equal to the ticket category id then category name show otherwise empty.

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya    
if ($category->id === $ticket->category_id) I've tried this as well not working

Comment: @Sumitkumar That is why I said check your database table `tickets` check any tickets exist.?

Comment: @Sumitkumar Best way to check this dump your `tickets` into the blade file.